# BI-DIRECTIONAL Oracle Golden Gate for Oracle 12c and SQL Server 2014

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, goldengate

I have two servers (both servers are on Windows OS):

- `Server_A` running Oracle 12c
- `Server_B` running SQL Server 2014

I want to implement data synchronization between them with Oracle Golden Gate technology.
I've downloaded these software from Oracle's website:

> - Oracle GoldenGate V12.1.2.1.0 for SQL Server on Windows (64 bit) (71 MB)
> - Oracle GoldenGate V12.1.2.1.0 for Oracle on Windows (64-bit) (239 MB)

1. Which one of these two software I have to install in each servers?
2. I want it to be BI-DIRECTIONAL.
3. How configure each servers to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2):

Install GoldenGate for SQL Server on the server with the SQL Server database.
Install GoldenGate for Oracle on the server with the Oracle database.

Here is an example of setting this up: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/oracle-sqlserver-goldengate-460262.html

It is outdated, but the point is, you can see what goes where in this.

Comment: I have read the guide in that link but, it is outdated as you mentioned, UNI-DIRECTIONAL and Oracle database OS is Linux not Windows. Also that link explanations is for one table not whole database.